# Google maps extension

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-maps-v2, android-maps-extensions

I want to use this google maps extension:

https://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/

however I didn't understand how do I combine it to my project?

I downloaded the zip in this website and I read the explanations on the website, however i still don't understand how do I combine it to my project?

(I have already installed the google_play_services in my eclipse, do I need to delete it?)

please, I want to learn for the first time and then I will implement it by myself

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You will have to delete google-play-services_lib from Eclipse and import android-maps-extensions instead. Android Maps Extensions includes everything from Google Play Services and only adds some code.

After that you have to make a few changes as explained on the site:

1. a couple of import statements,
2. SupportMapFragment (or MapView) full class names in xml and
3. call getExtendedMap instead of getMap on SupportMapFragment (or MapView).

Answer (score 0):

You can find out example from [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html).

Follow this [step](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/).